# Getting typescript error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type"

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to resolve a Typescript error I'm receiving without success.
I'm new to typescript and read a lot in the internet before I decided to as here.

The code is pretty simple and the code works well otherwise, but cant get around the typescript error:

> error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression
> of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; bio: {
> interests: { hoby: string; }; }; }'.   No index signature with a
> parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ name: string; bio: {
> interests: { hoby: string; }; }; }'.
>
> 18   return acc?.[curr];

Here is the sample code that results in the error:

```
/**
 * selected is "swimming" at the end because the reduce function is able to
 * traverse nested properties of the "sample" object
 */

const target = {
  bio: {
    interests: {
      hoby: "swimming"
    }
  }
};
const objectTree = ["bio", "interests", "hoby"];

const selected = objectTree.reduce((acc, curr) => acc?.[curr], target);
```

Comment: Because `objectTree` is just Array<string> type, not array of exclusively `target` properties. But why are you not using some robust function from existing library like lodash `get` that resolves object properties from tree?

Comment: `acc?.[curr as keyof typeof acc]`. You should also use a type-safe library to do this, or find one of the many stack overflow questions about type-safe deep property access (deep get, deep pick, strongly typed lodash get, etc).